# Is a Compass Swing Platform part of a runway or taxiway?

Tags: airport, airport-design

I am trying to work out if the compass swing platform is part of the runway or taxiway.

Comment: Why do you want to know? Right now, this reads like a trivia question rather than useful information, and "not useful" is a listed downvote reason.

Answer (score 3):

It could be on a taxiway, but it can also be outside the *movement area* (e.g. on the apron or ramp in the US). As far as I know, it is *never* on the runway.

There is a compass rose on a taxiway at **Petaluma Municipal Airport (O69)**. You can see it on the following image (from [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Petaluma+Municipal+Airport/@38.2602245,-122.6105674,124m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x8085b3e9b459123b:0x69be4d4b056292fe!8m2!3d38.2580396!4d-122.6086318)). It is painted in front of the hold short line of runway 11.

[image: Petaluma Municipal Airport]

---

Most airports will however have a dedicated position for the compass rose. This image (taken from [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25050/what-is-this-star-shaped-symbol-on-the-tarmac) question) shows an example at **Ramona Airport (KRNM)**:

[image: Ramona Airport]

It is not part of the taxiway as indicated by the yellow line, which separates the [non-movement area from the movement area](https://pilotworkshop.com/tips/movement-area/).