What is the purpose of these round paved pads?
What is the function of these round pads at KMWH, Grant County International Airport, in Moses Lake, WA? They appear to be sized to allow an aircraft to turn around, perhaps under its own power or for aircraft with a more limited turning radius, with tug assistance, but do they also contain tiedowns? Why is the left (western) one midway down a small runway? Any history on when they were constructed and why would be interesting.
Consulting airport taxiway diagrams, these do not appear to be a VOR check area, at least currently. Utilizing shapes like these for parking seems less efficient than the concrete shapes to the southeast (not shown below). I have searched for "round pad" and "cul-de-sac" with no success. 

To clarify: These pieces of pavement, including the circular areas at the end, are indeed depicted in light gray on the airport diagram. So they aren't just meant for ground vehicles, which was my first thought.

Compass Rose Pads makes sense, and is consistent with this related question: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25050/what-is-this-star-shaped-symbol-on-the-tarmac

These are now defunct compass rose pads, originally used to calibrate the compasses used in aircraft. You may notice that there are no compass markings on either of the pads, at least in your picture. If you zoom in on Google Maps you will see the remnants of these marks on at least one of the pads.

The FAA requires compass rose declination to be within half a degree, and surveys are recommended every five years. Most aircraft are now equipped with magnetometers and GPS and no longer need to calibrate using a fixed reference. With the shifting of the magnetic pole some four degrees over the last twenty years, maintaining these is more effort than it is worth.
Here is how they are used.

You can also just use a Master Compass.  I swing the wet compass on my homebuilt using a compass app on my phone as a master compass.
